# How to use WHERE clause in a query when number of columns is dynamic?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have searched this, but can't seem to find an answer:

I use the query function in a spreadsheet to collect comments from work assosiates. There is 17 commenters and I query from this week and ten weeks ahead. BUT, I only want the comments and not empty fields in my end result. I am almost there, but with the formula I use now, I have to manually update number of columns in the last part of the query, because the number of columns vary acording to number of comments. Here is my formula:

```
=transpose(query(transpose(query(QUERY(
IMPORTRANGE("1oQVZDEKLqx6ruz2yzIzUgppkWvBEOB_Eo-a4NW1WTSQ";"Comments!A1:U");
"select Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, 
Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19 where todate(Col1) > date '"&text(today()-7;
"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' limit 10");"select * where Col2<>'' or Col3<>'' or Col4<>'' or 
Col5<>'' or Col6<>'' or Col7<>'' or Col8<>'' or Col9<>'' or Col10<>'' or Col11<>'' or 
Col12<>'' or Col13<>'' or Col14<>'' or Col15<>'' or Col16<>'' or Col17<>'' or Col18<>''"));
"select * where Col2<>'' or Col3<>'' or Col4<>''"))
```

Is there any way to get this formula to work no matter how many columns the two "innermost" querys returns?

Here is the spreadsheet with the [queried comments](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hcnvhlCYXiaNmGIQKjqD7dD3gCKs9CXWOWqKoQ8n_Yo/edit?usp=sharing). It collects comments from [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oQVZDEKLqx6ruz2yzIzUgppkWvBEOB_Eo-a4NW1WTSQ/edit?usp=sharing) (in real life this is collected from 19 sheets with the importrange-formula).

I hope my question is understandable, and most of all, my problem solvable!

Comment: will you combine the multiple import range calls by row or by column? If by row will the column count always be the same? In your current query you only go up to check if column 18 is empty, not 19, and you are not pulling columns 20 and 21, is that on purpose?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, I ave corrected it now. In this example there is 17 commenters plus date (column A) and week number (column B).

Comment: And the number of commenters, so the number of columns will change? So you need to dynamically select and filter? What about the other questions

Comment: If I understand you correctly: tis is what I am trying to do (the number of columns is static in the spreadsheet that contains the comments that I query):Collect comments from the 17 commenters from this week and ten weeks forward, but only the columns with comments (query NO 2). Then query again after the transpose to get rid of the weeks that does not contain comments.

Comment: so the last query to get rid of weeks without comments is the one that troubles me: I dont know how many columns I have got.

Comment: Ah makes sense. I'll see if I can come up with something. Is there any chance a solution using Google Apps script would work? It's much better suited for this type of work

Comment: Yes, google script could absolutely be a solution, I guess. I just learned about the query function and thought that would be my solution, thats why I have focused only on a formula-based solution.

Comment: With a script solution I guess I even would be able to automatically hide the unused rows in the ten-row-field with no comments (in this example - row 8-14).

Comment: But my script-skills are not making me capable of doing this in at least a year...

Comment: Have you tried using the FILTER function? You would probably need to add an auxiliary row and a column, but nothing else, and the formulas would be infinitely easier. Something like this: `=FILTER(weeks, weekComments>0)`, `=FILTER(people, personComments>0)`,  `=FILTER(data, weeks=$A2, people=B$1)`

Comment: I tried the FILTER function just now, but with no success, I'm afraid. Do you mean formula one in A2, formula two in B1 and formula Three another place? Also, all the comments are text, so I tried with ISTEXT instead of >0. But I cannot get this to work. Maybe you could edit the sheet I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function removes empty columns and rows from a range that has row and column headers.
You can call it like this:

```
=FILTERROWSANDCOLS(IMPORTRANGE("1oQVZDEKLqx6ruz2yzIzUgppkWvBEOB_Eo-a4NW1WTSQ";"Comments!B1:U"))
```

Please note that I excluded column A for this.

```
function FILTERROWSANDCOLS(input) {
  function rowIsBlank(row) {
    return row.slice(1, row.length).join("") !== "";
  }

  return input.filter(rowIsBlank).transpose().filter(rowIsBlank).transpose();
}


Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "transpose", {value: function(){
  var output = [];
  for (var row = 0; row < this.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < this[row].length; col++) {
      if (row === 0){
        output.push([this[row][col]]); 
      } else {
        output[col].push(this[row][col]); 
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}});
```

Comment: Wow! Fantastic! This is exactly what I wanted. I can't thank you enough, it has been on my mind for so long.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can ask a followup question, or if I should post a new question. I will try, but just tell me if this is out of line. In my sheet I have preformated 10 rows down just in case there will be comments for all these weeks (and I have several of these preformated arrays under that). How can I then automatically hide the blank rows after I use your magic formula?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, can you show some pictures?

Comment: Here's a picture: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B23YdxUsz-BVZXVVa085LXQzY3AxWnpqZzJCVHE5WE5NMi1N

Comment: You could combine the two `={FILTERROWSANDCOLS(IMPORTRANGE("1oQVZDEKLqx6ruz2yzIzUgppkWvBEOB_Eo-a4NW1WTSQ";"Comments!B1:U"));=FILTERROWSANDCOLS(IMPORTRANGE("1oQVZDEKLqx6ruz2yzIzUgppkWvBEOB_Eo-a4NW1WTSQ";"ANOTHERRANGE"))}`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't manage to apply this. I get an #ERROR! Could you try to edit my sheet to show me? Anyway, thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Is it still the same sheet? The screenshot looks likes it's another one

Comment: It is not the same sheet, but my original sheet I wan't to apply this to. I took a picture of that to hopefully show why I want to hide the rows without comments from every 10-weekarray.